# Other sites for rock ID questions

Tags: discussion

Following the decision to render all rock and mineral ID questions off-topic I have begun searching for other sites, similar to Stack Exchange’s forum layout, that I could ask such questions on in the future.

Can anyone recommend other sites or resources that would prove useful, should I need help identifying a mineral in the future.

Comment: Related: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/there-are-cloud-identification-guides-are-there-also-guided-rock-identificati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you a site for an individual question where, if you post a good picture with geological info, you might receive more answers than here in the past (it is not a single answer forum as this one, answers are discussions).

https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?board=15.0

What I am not sure is if mods could recommend the site collectively for all the users coming from Google without permission of the webmasters of naked science.